# compile fails as library missing for Gnucobol DB2 program

Tags: compiler-errors, db2, gnucobol

Gnucobol - db2 program.sqb, Preprocess done. Compile of program.cbl fails -

DB2Express-C running inside a container & GnuCobol installed in VM

DB2 pre-process successful
Preprocessing done against DB2 server running inside a container

```
$ db2 "prep SQLCOBPGM.sqb bindfile target ANSI_COBOL"
$ ls
db2inst1  isus  log  SQLCOBPGM.bnd  `enter code here`SQLCOBPGM.cbl  SQLCOBPGM.sqb  sqllib
```

Compilation fails
For compile .cbl & sql libraries are copied to ubuntu VM that has GnuCobol installed

> **# cobc -static SQLCOBPGM.cbl -L/db2home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64 -ldb2 -x -O /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb2 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

cobc compiler failed as /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb2
Are we missing some libraries?

Comment: Is there anything missing in the answers? If yes, please comment, if everything is fine, please accept/vote on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified both a library to link (db2) and a library path for the lookup, which seems fine.
In 99% the error is that either the path specified does not contain a libdb2 file (I suggest to add the output of `ls /db2home/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64/libdb2*` to the question) or the library doesn't match the architecture of the linker (cobc and ld are 64 bit executables, aren't they?), or the exucuting user doesn't have read permissions on the libraries / execute rights on its path.

Comment: lib path corrected; lbd2 error resolved. However "Cannot find module 'sqlgstrt' " error turns up; so added  -ldb2api to resolve it, but somehow that library is shown missing again. Shown path here >:/home/mmsuser/cobdb2/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64# ls -l
libdb2o.so -> libdb2o.so.1
libdb2o.so.1
libdb2apie.so -> libdb2apie.so.1
libdb2apie.so.1 2                                            # cobc SQLCOBPGM.cbl -std=default -I/home/mmsuser/cobdb2/db2inst1/sqllib/include/cobol_mf -L/home/mmsuser/cobdb2/db2inst1/sqllib/lib64 -ldb2 -ldb2api -x
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb2api

Comment: I don't know where those are to be found, but if it is in the api then the name (from the ls output you've provided) then the library would be  `-db2apie`, but I question if you really need it. I assume you've seen http://db2twilight.blogspot.com/2014/01/linuxdb2-running-cobol-with-inline-sql.html ...
You may also go into details checking with `nm some.so  | grep " T "` for exported functions to see if / where sqlgrst is defined.

Comment: Thanks Simon -ldb2apie helps - compiled, bind also done. But alas gets this compile time error at runtime ># ./arun2
libcob: Cannot find module 'sqlgstrt'  - Yes I have seen the blogspot article and did try pre-compile/bind against DB2 & compile/run in Ubuntu VM; Confused on what's missing

Comment: Just to recheck: db2apie is 64bit correct? Is cobc also 64 bit?
If both are of the same architecture: is there an entry point named `sqlgsrt` (see the `nm` invocation shown above)? Maybe it is upper-case in the library?

Comment: Simon, it did work finally; esqlOC for pre-process cobc -static to compile, odbc.ini updated with DB2 driver & Connect string set as Db, driver, uid/pwd did t trick >esqlOC -static -o arun.cob db2cobpgm.sqb >cobc -x -static -locsql -L/usr/local/lib arun.cob for pre-process/compile >./sql Conn String:-DBALIAS=SAMPLE;DRIVER=/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1/lib64/libdb2o.so;UID=db2inst1;PWD=** OCSQL: DB connecting using SQLDriverConnect >OCSQL: PREPARE I/O SELECT EMPNO,WORKDEPT FROM DB2INST1.EMP WHERE EMPNO = ?>SQLCODE:-+000000000
SQLSTATE:-00000
Employee:-000010
Dept     :-A00

Comment: @Arun if you have a different answer _to the original question_ then please post it as answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that the directory you specify for the libraries:

- is present
- is readable by the user performing the compilation
- contains all required libraries (over 100 of them), including libd2.so.1 etc.

So the Db2-express installation must choose the relevant option to add the artefacts for development (includes, libraries/shared-objects etc).

Works for me on Linux with cobc. I also ensure LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes that directory to allow resulting compiled programs to run.

Comment: Why should the load library path has any effect on the linking? The link path was specified with -L already (and would be specified with LIBRARY_PATH otherwise, won't it)?